# How to identify unused indexes in a Firebase Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have an application that uses Firebase Firestore. This is a great platform and my application grows every day, as well as my indexes. However, I suspect that they have unnecessary indexes. But I don't know how to identify them.

Is there a way to find this out in the Firestore?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this helps:

1. Use the Firestore console to list all of your indexes.
2. For each index, check the Usage column. If the usage is zero, then the index is not being used.
3. You can also use the Firestore CLI to list all of your indexes and their usage.
4. Once you have identified unused indexes, you can delete them to improve the performance of your application.

```
firebase firestore indexes list
firebase firestore indexes delete <index-name>
```

Comment: Where do you see a "Usage" column?

Comment: There is no usage column

Answer (score -3):

I'm not aware of an automated solution to identify unused indexes, but you only need an index for fields that are explicitly used in your queries (e.g. for sorting).

I'd manually delete indexes that you suspect aren't used. If you happen to delete one that's actually needed then you'll know immediately because Firestore will simply error when you make the query. The error message should contain a link to set up the required index.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

> As you use and test your app, Cloud Firestore generates error messages that help you create additional indexes your app requires.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @geg. But my application is currently very large, as well as the indexes. Deleting manually is a possibility, but I would have to test several points on my system to make sure the index is not actually being used

Comment: The "scream test" (delete a suspected unused index, and see what errors your app runs into) isn't really an appropriate way to find out which indexes are unused, for a production app. It implies downtime.

Especially because, if you get it wrong on a large table, you'll be down for a long time while the backfill runs to recreate the index

Comment: Agreed – in hindsight this approach isn't sensible for production apps.